Are singletons open in the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$?
I'm pretty sure they're not, but I keep getting stuck on the idea that I can construct a singleton via $\{a\} = \bigcup_n [a, a+\frac{1}{n})$, i.e. as a union of open sets. What am I missing here?

You're mixing up union and intersection.

Oh my goodness, you're right.

:-) it happens!
